# In Lasso 9, does -recordindex parameter of field method exist? Alternatives?

Tags: lasso-lang

In old Lasso 8 code, I would frequently use `field('foo', -recordindex=(loop_count - 1))` in a conditional to display a header row in a table when a value changed between records.

In Lasso 9, the `-recordindex` parameter seems to be ignored. It's also not documented.

My first workaround would be to set a variable with each record iteration and compare the current record's field against that value.

```
<?= var('lastSortFieldValue') = null ?>
[records]
    [if(field('sortField') != $lastSortFieldValue)]
        <!-- display header -->
    [/if]
    <!-- display row -->
    <?= $lastSortFieldValue = field('sortField') =>
[/records]
```

Any recommendations for a best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workaround of setting the variable is probably the best thing to do. (Though I would make it a local variable instead of a thread variable as it probably doesn't need to have thread scope.)

If you really wanted a method that would do what field(..., -recordIndex) used to do, then here's a method to do that:

```
define fieldFromRow(field::string, row::integer) => {
    local(curMap = inline_scopeGet)
    !#curMap || #curMap->size == 0? return null;

    local(stashRow) = #curMap->find(::currentrow)
    handle => {
        #curMap->insert(::currentrow = #stashRow)
    }

    #curMap->insert(::currentrow = #curMap->find(::currentset)->get(INLINE_RESULTROWS_POS)->get(#row))

    return column(#field)
}
```

This method gets the current inline information. Then it stashes the current row and sets a handler to restore the current row when all is said and done. It then sets the current row to the one specified in the method call and returns the value for the specified field. A bit of a hack, but it works in my basic testing.

Comment: Very helpful work-around! Thank you for the custom method. I put that in LassoStartup for my instance and quickly converted all occurrences of the old way to the temporary new way. How do you find all these secret types and methods, like inline_scopeGet and INLINE_RESULTROWS_POS? :-)

Comment: I agree with Jolle, while elegant this solution increases overhead unnecessarily. Justin, your first approach was probably the most efficient.

Comment: I, too, agree with Jolle and Ke - use this method to get things working, but as stated above, your solution of using a variable is the best approach. (By the way, my solution could be made faster by not using column to grab the data, but that might cause unexpected results in edge cases.)

Answer (score 1):

However elegant Brads custom method is I would advice against using it. It is slower than setting and comparing a local variable.

```
local(
    timer,
    loops = 1000,
    present_value,
    prev_value,
    out = string,
    result = string
)

inline(-database = 'mysql', -sql = "SELECT * FROM help_category") => {

    #timer = micros

    loop(#loops) => {
        rows => {
            #present_value = field('name')
            #prev_value != #present_value ? #out -> append('<hr />Here be a new field<br />')
            #out -> append(#present_value + '<br />')
            #prev_value = #present_value
        }
    }
    #result -> append('Result using local ' + ((micros - #timer) / # loops) + '<br />')

    #timer = micros

    loop(#loops) => {
        rows => {
            #present_value = field('name')
            loop_count > 1 and #prev_value != fieldFromRow(#present_value, loop_count -1) ? #out -> append('<hr />Here be a new field<br />')
            #out -> append(#present_value + '<br />')
        }
    }
    #result -> append('Result using fieldFromRow ' + ((micros - #timer) / # loops) + '<br />')

}
#result
```

-> Result using local 637
Result using fieldFromRow 1612

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In my implementation of Brad's custom method, I added a step that logs the usage so I can go back later and clean it up. For now, it was a simple regex find and replace to make a lot of stuff start working. Thanks again for the detailed look at this.